# Extract query string from local a href

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a tweak script / extension to an existing website. There is a `<a href` that points to a local file (like `<a href='/thing.php?id=123&section=456'>`) I want to extract the id, `123` in that case. Currently it does `$('#theID').attr('href').split('&')[0].split('=')[1]);` which is cursed.

However, I cannot do `new URL($('#theID').attr('href')).searchParams.get('id')` because I get `Uncaught TypeError: URL constructor: /thing.php?id=123&section=456 is not a valid URL.` How can I properly parse this?

Comment: `/thing.php` is not a URL, it's a path. Append such as `http://example.com` to create a valid URL for the constructor. `new URL("http://example.com" + $('#theID').attr('href'))`. Althought, if you already have an element with the ID appended dynamically... there's proobaaaaably a much better way to do this. Without the search parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are retrieving the URL from an anchor tag, you can use its properties. The query string can be retrieved from [the `search` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils/search). Then you can manually parse the query string or use the [new `URLSearchParams` feature](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) to parse it.

For example:

```
var a = document.getElementById("test");
var search = a.search;
var parsed = new URLSearchParams(search);
var q = parsed.get("q");
alert(q);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/uwo2a17p/